# How do I count maps in an array in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How do I get the number of maps in the following?

```
[{:a "a"} {:b "b"}]
```

I'm expecting `2`.

Comment: Do you just want the length of the vector or could it also contain non-map items e.g. `[{:a "a"} 1 :foo {:b "b"}]`?

Comment: In my case, the number of maps was what I was after, but this works too.

I had managed to redefine count (see comment below) which is why I thought count wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `count`:

```
(def data [{:a "a"} {:b "b"}] )
(count data) => 2
```

You may also be interesed in these websites:

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)

Comment: Lol... ok... I had managed to redefine count in my namespace which was throwing an wrong arity error.

Answer (score -2):

Create a df(definition)and assign the variable to (atom 0) and count within doseq.

eg 
(df count-var (atom 0))
(doseq [n vec-of-maps]

(swap! cnt-var + 1))